# How can I block cookies from a specific URL (not the whole domain)?

Tags: firefox, cookies, ublock-origin

I've noticed that some Google cookies are slowing down Google Maps in Firefox.  I'd like to block any Google cookies set when navigating to `google.com/maps`, but not block cookies for other Google URLs (e.g. login cookies).  Is there a way to do this?